# Trust Wallet WEB API for transferring funds within trust wallet

Tags: php-curl, erc20, trustwallet

> I want to integrate "trustwallet.com" with my web. Use case is
> transferring fund trustwallet to trustwallet using private website.
> Would it be possible to show trustwallet amount on website using any
> API or something else.

During my R&D I came across few solution like

1. use of https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/6140048/Tz5p6JL7#intro - Is this good option and is it created by Trust Wallet, can anyone use this without any doubt.
2. https://developer.trustwallet.com/ this guide is have mobile solution and code but does not have any straightforward way or REST API to integrate with website.